# Rails return an object from an action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to return an object(@state) along with true or false from rails method in application helper.

I have a model named User which calls an action which is in applicaiton helper.

```
class User
include ApplicationHelper

*****-----_********

  def user_state
   user = self
   state = get_state(user)
  end

end
```

in applicaiton helper,

```
def get_state (user)
 @user = User.find(user.id)
 @state = UserState.where('user_id = ?',@user.id)
 if @state.present?
  *** here I want to return @state along with true **** 
  return true 
 else
  return false
 end
end
```

I tried 'return @state and true' didn't work but, 'return @state' worked.

Seems to me either object or a boolean can be returned and not both at once.

Is there any way to return both of them. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure a "Helper" is what you need here, but returning multiple values from a ruby method is pretty easy:

```
def myfun(x)
  if x
    [true, "one"] # or use return true, "one"
  else
    false
  end
end

a, b = myfun(true)
p a, b # prints true, "one"

a, b = myfun(false)
p a, b # prints  false, nil
```